# Search Engines for Password Protected Sites

Tags: search

Our institution is moving away from Google Search Appliance since it has been discontinued.  They are switching over to Google Custom Search Engine for our sites.

We have one site that is password protected so CSE won't work for it.  Has anyone had experience with other web search solutions that work with password protected sites?  It can be hosted locally on our server or cloud based, provided that data isn't accessible to everyone, like it would be with Google.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally reviewed many of the replacement appliances you can find listed on Gartner's 2017 Magic Quadrant (a popular industry reports that talks about leading enterprise search engines), so feel I can give you an unbiased and informed opinion here.

If you are looking for an on-premises solution like GSA, at a similar price,  that are capable of working with password protected sites and much more, I would recommend these:

1. Lucidworks Fusion: excellent choice, well polished admin console, super fast to get search instances running. This will feel like a nice upgrade from your GSA setup. They also have a very good list of existing clients. Build on top of Lucene/SOLR and main driving force between SOLR. They have some good AI under-the-hood too, so you don't need an army of editors to be continually tuning your engine (though it doesn't hurt). If you would like to test it, you can download a trial version from their site.  https://lucidworks.com/
2. MindBreeze: very similar to GSA, physical server you can install in your data center. Easy to tune. You'll get similar relevancy as per GSA with just the basic tuning. Interface feels a little dated for my liking. https://www.mindbreeze.com/
3. SearchBlox: a lower cost solution you install on VM. A little more basic than the others, but cheap and cheerful. They also have a 30 day trial version that you can install on local VM for testing purposes. https://www.searchblox.com/

If you want something cloud-based, you have plenty of options too. Lucidworks and SearchBlox can both be installed on AWS and other cloud platforms. You also have some of the market leader options too, such as [Attivio](https://www.attivio.com/), [Sinequa](https://www.sinequa.com/) and [Coveo](https://www.coveo.com/). They are great, but I suspect offer a little more than you need (and can get costly).